# Solve $1+2^x+2^{2x+1}=y^2$ for integers $x,y>0\,$ [IMO 2006 P4]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

What are the solutions in positive integers of the equation: 
$${1+2^x+2^{2x+1}=y^2}$$
I tried to factorize the equation but it didn't help much.
Clearly $y $ is an odd integer. Substituting $y =2n+1$, we get 
$2^x+2^{2x+1}=(2n)\cdot{(2n+2)}$
$\Rightarrow (2^{x-2})\cdot(1+2^{x+1})=(n)\cdot(n+1)$
Which is the product of 2 consecutive integers. Does it help? I don't know.

Comment: For displayed equations use \$\$x\$\$ instead of \$x\$.

Comment: http://olympiads.win.tue.nl/imo/imo2006/solutions.pdf I remember this problem instantly because i was an IMO contestant.

Comment: @David Thanks man. Works perfectly!

Comment: @MridulSachdeva Hello there :)! I fail to understand: for (2n+1)^2, you get 2n(2n+1) + 2n + 1. I can see how the 1 from both sides cancel but what happened to the 2n term? Also for the second step, it seems to that the LHS has been factorized after having been divided by 4. But how can the same have been done to the RHS?? - sure both 2n became n (division by 2*2), but what about the  + 1, should that not become 0.5???? Sorry if I am being silly, but I am baffled!

Comment: @Just_a_fool I am sorry.My mistake(typo). I have edited the question

Answer (score 1):

$1+2^x+2^{2x+1}=y^2$ or $1+2^{(x-1)+1}+2^{2(x-1)+3}=y^2$ or $1+2*2^{(x-1)}+8*2^{2(x-1)}=y^2$. Now, let $p=2^{(x-1)}$, then, $1+2p+p^2+7p^2=y^2$ or $(p+1)^2=y^2-7p^2$ , this a Rational Pell equation, now, it can be shown that any such Pell equation has solutions; $(r^2-d)^2=(r^2+d)^2-d(2r)^2$. Hence, by comparison, $d=7$, $p(=2^{(x-1)})=2r$, $y=r^2+7$ and $p+1=r^2-7$, from these equations we get; $8=r^2-2r=r(r-2)$. Hence, $r=4=2^{(x-2)}$. $x=4$, $y=23$. This is the only non-trivial integer solution.

Answer (score -2):

Let $2^x = z$, then: $2z^2 + z + y^2 - 1 = 0$.

Calculate $\triangle = 1^2 - 4\cdot 2\cdot (y^2 - 1) = 9 - 8y^2$.

$\triangle > 0 \iff 9 - 8y^2 > 0 \iff y^2 < \dfrac{9}{8} = 1.11$, so $y = 1$, and $\triangle = 1$. So $z = \dfrac{-1 \pm 1}{2\cdot 2} = 0$ or $-0.5$, but $z =2^x > 2$. So there is no solution.

In fact $\triangle = 1^2 - 4\cdot 2\cdot (1-y^2) = 8y^2 - 7$. Now we solve the Pell equation:

$8y^2 - 7 = k^2$ or $8y^2 - k^2 = 7$. This has an initial solution $(y_0,k_0) = (1,1)$. Using this we can generate the general solution, then we can find $z$, and then $x$.

Comment: If we put $2^x=z$, the equation will become $2z^2+z+1-y^2=0$

Comment: thanks, and it accidentally creates an interesting situation.

Comment: So you realize that your solution is wrong.

Comment: Can it be really done this way ,if yes please guide me!!