# Given that a is an integer, find possible $a$'s so that $2^{2a+1}+2^a+1$ is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, square-numbers

I found this question in an old Olympiad from my country, but the solution I found only provides a brute force approach.

The solution said $0$ and $4$, and when it reaches the point it tests $8$, the solution stops there.

I wonder if there is another way to solve it?

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Please [show context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) so that you can get a good answer. To do this, would you mind typing the solution up?

Comment: Also, linked from the duplicate, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/808509/115115 has some more answers.

Comment: Is http://olympiads.win.tue.nl/imo/imo2006/solutions.pdf the original solution you mentioned?