# Determine all $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ such that $1+2^x+2^{2x+1}=y^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> Determine all $x,y \in \Bbb Z$ such that $$1+2^x+2^{2x+1}=y^2$$

I've managed to show that $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$ are solutions. I've also noted that if $(x,y)$ is a solution, then $(x,-y)$ is also a solution. Also I've managed to show that negative $x$ there is no solutions.

For $x=1$ we have that $1+2+2^3 = 11$ that isn't a square and for $x=2$  we have that $1+2^2+2^5 = 37$ which also isn't a square.

For $x=3$ we get $1+2^3+2^7 = 137 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and since squares are either $0,1$ modulo $3$ we can conclude that $x=3$ is also not a solution.

My approach was to determine the residue of $$1+2^x+2^{2x+1} \pmod 3$$ and see for what $x$ it's either $0$ or $1$ as those would imply that it's a square.

Now $$1+2^x+2^{2x+1}=1+2^x(2^{x+1}+2) \equiv 0,1 \pmod 3$$ if either $2^x(2^{x+1}+1) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ or $2^x(2^{x+1}+1) \equiv -1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$.

For the former if $2^x(2^{x+1}+1) \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, then either $2^x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ or $2^{x+1}+1 \equiv 0\pmod 3$. $2^x \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ is never true so $2^{x+1}+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3 \iff 2^{x+1} \equiv -1  \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ and this is true when $x=0$

For the latter i.e  $2^x(2^{x+1}+1) \equiv -1 \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ this is never true so the only thing I'm left with is the case when $x=0$.

This makes me feel that the only solutions are $(0,2)$ and $(0,-2)$? Am I missing something important here?

Comment: A more general question (for your case $x \ne 0$) would be: which perfect squares have exactly three nonzero bits when written in base $2$?  I suspect the answer is: none.

Comment: Apparently you need some Pell equation theory here, see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808509/solve-the-following-equation-in-positive-integers-x-and-y). Once you're convinced this answers your question, we can close as duplicate. (The IMO solution doesn't use Pell theory, and is quite simple in structure)

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer Why don't you close it directly? It looks like an exact duplicate.

Comment: $2^{x+1}\equiv 2 \mod 3$ is true for more than just $x = 0$.

Comment: @WhatsUp You're right, I'll do that right now. I think [this link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/808509/solve-the-following-equation-in-positive-integers-x-and-y) answers the question.